# Changing Navigationview item selected background

Tags: uwp-xaml

Is there anyway to modify the default background when item is selected in a NavigationView? I want to change the background of the item when it is selected. I have been trying using code that make SelectedItem to null and setting the item's normal background (which is a different attribute from selection background) but that don't really work since nulling does not deselect the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Changing Navigationview item selected background

[`NavigationViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem) has many theme static resource, If you want to edit the color of selected background, you just create new `SolidColorBrush` resource to override the default value in `Application.Resources` just like the follow.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected"/>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

[image]

Comment: This works but the color persists even after selecting another item Any work around this?

Comment: Worked after updating to a pre-release version of Microsoft.UI.Xaml pre-release 2.5.0